# Input layout reuse / abstraction from shader?

Tags: directx, hlsl, directx-11, sharpdx

In DirectX 11 input layout requires getting the shader signature, however i'm only using a single input for all my shaders and i'd like to reuse it.

Is it possible to create an input layout WITHOUT passing in a shader (i'm fine with losing the validation)?
If not, is it safe to reuse the input layout across diferent shaders if i create it with a shader signature that is common to my other shaders?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no possibility to create an input layout without passing in a shader, but it is safe to reuse the input layout with other shaders that have the same vertex attributes.

Comment: Thanks, will go for that then, make a stub shader that does nothing with the signature i need & reuse the layout, thanks